# mostjs - creating streams from custom sources

Tags: javascript, observable, cujojs, mostjs

I am curious about current best practices for creating streams from sources that may not conform to an existing stream creation method (https://github.com/cujojs/most/blob/master/docs/api.md)

Example using Firebase's `ref.on('child_added', function(snap){})`:

```
most.fromEvent('child_added', ref) //ERROR
```

> I can't use `.fromEvent`... although ref implements some sort of `on`, it does not seem to conform to the EventEmitter interface (addEventListener, removeEventListener)

---

```
ref.on('child_added', function(snap){ emitter.emit('value', snap) })

most.fromEvent('value', emitter)
```

> Manually emitting events, is the best I can think of at the moment...

---

```
// https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/create.md

Rx.Observable.create(function(observer){
  ref.on('child_added', function(snap){ observer.next(snap) })
})
```

> Is there a similar mechanism to custom create a stream, a la Rx?

Are there better ways I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Check on how to use `@most/create`

https://github.com/mostjs/create

It allows to manually emit events - similar to how you would do it with `rxJS`

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be to shim the interface that your firebase library exposes to fit most's `fromEvent` constructor.

Looking at the source code for `fromEvent`, we can see that it supports two interfaces for event sources:

- [`{ addEventListener, removeEventListener }`](https://github.com/cujojs/most/blob/a892f269b453f513d4855bda21e9ae2aceb9de5e/src/source/fromEvent.js#L21-L26) — the [EventTarget interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget), commonly implemented by DOM elements
- [`{ addListener, removeListener }`](https://github.com/cujojs/most/blob/a892f269b453f513d4855bda21e9ae2aceb9de5e/src/source/fromEvent.js#L27-L28) — the [EventEmitter interface](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html), found often in node libraries

With that knowledge, we can implement a shim function to create a stream from the `{ on, off }` interface:

```
function fromEvent (eventName, source) {
  if (typeof source.on === 'function' && typeof source.off === 'function') {
    return most.fromEvent(eventName, {
      addListener: source.on,
      removeListener: source.off
    });
  } else {
    return most.fromEvent.apply(null, arguments)
  }
}
```

This can be nicer than using `create`, as [the EventEmitterSource](https://github.com/cujojs/most/blob/a892f269b453f513d4855bda21e9ae2aceb9de5e/src/source/EventEmitterSource.js) performs scheduling of the event on the next tick of the event loop, and handles disposing of the event listener when the stream ends.